# Session Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with session in CI

When I do:

```
if no exists:
$_SESSION['test'] = 0;
if exist:
$foo = $_SESSION['test'];
$_SESSION['test'] = ++$foo;
echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

And it works perfect. Autoincrementing every load

But, if I do:

```
if no exist:
$this->session->set_userdata('test', 0);
if exists:
$s = $this->session->userdata('test');
$s++;
$this->session->set_userdata('test', $s);
var_dump($this->session->userdata('test'));
```

it doesn't work...

What I missed?

Thanks!

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: Do you load session library?

Comment: I load the library. First I enter to the page I get 0, after 1, but if refresh I get 1 all the time. But with $_SESSION[] I get 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6...

Comment: @ChittaranjanSethi I want to upload my session in every refresh, but it  doesnt update with session of CI, but with native session it works perfect